# Cross-platform widget toolkit

Tags: c, cross-platform, gui-toolkit

I'm looking for a cross-platform widget toolkit that I can use for a C application that I'm developing. This application will only serve as a small front-end. I'm keen on good design and usability. Speed is less of a priority, but I'd still like something lightweight.

I realise similar questions have been asked, but I'd like an answer based on my requirements.

Comment: Are you doing just plain C instead of C++? And which platforms are you targeting? You want answers more specific to your requirements, you'd better be more specific on them.

Comment: @Stephen Chu: C, as the tag suggests. I don't think target platform matters too much. By cross-platform, I mean it should target as many platforms as possible, because I'm not certain what the end-user is going to be using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For C, I'd say the prime canditate is [gtk](http://www.gtk.org/). You'd want to use C++ for [qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) or [wxwidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/), though the latter also has lua (yay!) bindings, which is *the* C way to get around [Greenspun's tenth rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_Tenth_Rule). Depending on your application domain less-hyped (but still mature) libraries like [agar](http://libagar.org/) deserve some consideration. I'd mention [fltk](http://www.fltk.org/) if it weren't for C++, too. Truly leet people would use [xaw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xaw) and have users install an X server under windows. On an again more serious note, [eagle](http://eaglemode.sourceforge.net/) has to be mentioned just for coolness value, although being C++, too. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits#Based_on_C_or_C.2B.2B_.28including_bindings_to_other_languages.29) gives yet more options.

Comment: Are you sure wxWidgets is usable from C? It supports quite a few languages, but I'm not aware of C support.

Comment: Thanks. Agar looks interesting. I'll look into it as well as GTK+.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious choice for C would probably be [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) (and yes, despite the "+" in the name, it's a C toolkit, though you can certainly use it from C++).

Answer (score 0):

I would say, use [GTK-server](http://www.gtk-server.org/).